# Accessing webservice from remote machine

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I've developed a simple web service and hosted it on one of my machines in a LAN environment, but when i try to access the web service from another machine within LAN i got a prompt asking for username and password, web service is configured to be accessed anonymously. It is working fine on the machine where it's hosted. What's wrong with the settings, am i missing something?

This is a web service written in ASP.NET and hosted on IIS in machine say 192.168.1.1 and i wanted to access it on 192.168.1.2, the address of the web service is 192.168.1.1/myService/service.asmx but it keep displaying me username/password prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Anonymous Authentication feature enabled in IIS: [Enable Anonymous Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using Windows xp and the version of IIS is 5.1 and I've already enabled the anonymous access, and **Use Integrated Windows Authentication** checkbox is already checked.

Comment: Ah, Windows XP. Uncheck the Integrated Windows Authentication, that's the opposite of anonymous.

Comment: You also have to make sure the IUSR_machinename (or if it's the ASPNET user, I forget) has read/list access (NTFS) to the directory where your site is stored.

Comment: IIS is using IUSR_machinename for annonymous authentication can you please tell me how can i give this user permission to access my web service directory.

Comment: Right-click the folder, select Security, add the IUSR_xxx (and perhaps the ASPNET) user and make sure Read and List are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. We were using "Windows Authentication" and could not use "Anonymous Authentication" for this project.

We were deploying an msi to test on VM's. I added the pre-compiled version of the 'asmx.cs' to the /bin directory of the installation. I only added the 'asmx' file to the root directory and this worked for me.

Hope that helps.